# Can I use "where 'search_word' like 'field'" in sql?

Tags: php, sql, fuelphp

I want to set the field to the right and the seach word to the left.

This is a normal SQL like search.

```
select id where id like '1'
```

I want to do like this.

```
select id where '1' like id
```

I 've tried these in fuelphp.

```
$query ->where($search_word,'like','field'); 

$query ->where($search_word,'like',DB::expr("CONCAT('%','field','%'")); 

$query ->where('field','like',DB::expr("CONCAT('%',$search_word,'%'"));
```

These returned sql syntax error.

How wrong is these?

Comment: LIKE without wildcards (e.g. %), doesn't make much sense. Why not use = instead?

Comment: The search word is longer than the field value. For examle, the field value in sql is "apple" and the seach word is "orangeappledog". So,I can't use "=". It is difficult to explain,though.

Answer (score 0):

Try to specify like:

```
$query ->where(1,'like', $search_word);
```